# '+' symbol gets replaced by space in request paramters of Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

When the text is entered in a text field of JSP containing any '+' symbol in it, it is getting replaced by space when the parameter value is retrieved inside the servlet through request.getParameter("abc").

I read a few blogs and came to know that encoding needs to be done to successfully read the exact text but it is not clear to me. Can someone please help me out on this.

Comment: Show your code , the relevant part.. Servlet should take care of this.

Comment: "+" is the url encoding result of " " (space) and a plus sign should be %2B.

Comment: I know that "+" is the url encoding result of " " (space) but what if I am actually typing in '+'. how to resolve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

`+` is illegal inside a parameter value, as it is the defined separator between parameter name-value pairs. You need to `URLEncode` both parameter names and parameter values before sending.

Comment: And you also need to _decode_ those parameters on the server side, to get back your original text.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, it's a JSP, it will happen automatically, as it will in any servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce.

Even with

```
<form action="rep" method="GET">
    <input name="foo" type="text"/>
</form>
```

the servlet at `rep` (even if is is a jsp) receives `foo=a%2Bb` as query string when I type `a+b` in the input field.

I suppose you are *manually* generating the query, and in that case, you **must** url encode the parameters.

Comment: Adding a link to a url encoding post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript

Comment: @Teddy : where did OP speak of javascript ?

Comment: By your argument, he is manually generating it. I assumed it must be with Java script. Although it could be generated in scriptlet also.

Comment: @Teddy : I think you are right, he must be using JavaScript. My comment was not against you, but more on the question that should precise the context since it is not a simple browser.

Comment: I was using an AJAX method to submit the form. Wanted to know if there is a way to do it in AJAX or javascript way. I tried using URIComponentEncoder but it didnt work. For time being have replaced + by %2B in the text fields and it has worked for me. But I was looking for a solution in AJAX or javascript way.

Comment: @Arunabh : so edit your question to say it, and add relevant tags. But I'm afraid your question is just a duplicate than the one proposed by Teddy.